Numba AOT using setuptools compiles .pyd, import pyd causes recompilation. Why?
I have some code, generic numba.  I'm attempting to compile it with setuptools, which I've done successfully before on this computer, in this environment, but lost my setup.py file.  Code to compile immediately below.  Setup.py below that.
Running python setupnumba.py build_ext --inplace throws no errors, and creates a pyd file, but it doesn't appear as if it's actually compiling the code.  When I import the code it appears to be treating it as a regular python file with a JIT encoder, and it's running it.   if I protect some code inside 'File to compile' with if name='main', it will run that code on import.  In the print monitor, on import, it prints
temp.c
temp.cxx
No idea what's going on.  What I had to do was rebuild the setup.py from scratch, and I did it based on numba's documentation, so I think there's an issue there.
File to compile
from numba.pycc import CC
import numpy as np


cc = CC('nufit1d')

@cc.export('jacg1dsup', 'f8[:,:](f8[:],f8,f8,f8,f8)')
def jacg1dsup(x, aa, bb, cc, dd):
    xx = x[0:-1]
    size = xx.size
    j = np.empty((size, 4))
    j[:, 0] = np.ones(size)
    j[:, 1] = np.exp(-2 * (xx - cc) ** 2 / (np.abs(dd) + 0.5) ** 2)
    j[:, 2] = 4 * bb * (xx - cc) / (np.abs(dd) + 0.5) ** 2 * np.exp(-2 * (xx - cc) ** 2 / (np.abs(dd) + 0.5) ** 2)
    j[:, 3] = bb * (4 * (xx - cc) ** 2 / (np.abs(dd) + 0.5) ** 3) * np.exp(-2 * (xx - cc) ** 2 / (np.abs(dd) + 0.5) ** 2)
    return j

The setup.py file
from setuptools import setup, Extension
from numba.pycc import CC




setup(
    name='nufit1d',
    ext_modules=[Extension('nufit1d', sources=['nfit1d.py'])],
)


Numa AOT is really not great. It is less flexible than Cython, can usually produce slower codes and does not support some critical features (not to mention is is also less stable than Cython). Packaging also tends to be more complicated with Numba. I advise you to use Cython for AOT compilation. It is specifically designed for that purpose.

By the way, for sake of performance, you should use a loop instead of j[:, 0] = ..., j[:, 1] = ..., etc. accesses (unless your array is relatively small and fits in the CPU caches). The current pattern is memory bound and Numba can hardly optimise it (the array is not guaranteed to be contiguous and the strides can cause some complex overlapping resulting in aliasing issue). Numba and Cython like loops (as opposed to pure-Python)

Larger context: applying 1d fits to large numbers of relatively small datasets using scipy.optimize.least_squares
Trying different combinations, for this application, I've tested a lot of different combinations of cython, numba, and multiprocessing.  By a small margin, the fastest is to use cython to loop over subsections of data and call precompiled numba functions to feed least_squares inside the cython code after breaking up larger chunks with multiprocessing.  The largest speedup is numba, and this holds true when compared against cython for the same sub-task.

Theoretically, Numba JIT and Cython can be equally fast. Numba AOT have some strong limitation preventing it to be as fast as Cython in some cases. Cython needs to be tuned so to be as fast as Numba JIT. For example, the Numba JIT enable AVX2 when available and even AVX-512 (or SVE on ARM) while Cython is compiled for a 20 years old CPU by default like any C/C++ program. One need to enable that (at the example of retro-compatibility issues on CPUs are are not even used any-more anyway) as well as advanced optimizations and other some tuning (eg. wraparound, bound checking, native divs, etc.).

The only main downside of Cython performance-wise (beside the above arch tuning) is that Numpy operations are not optimized so you need to use basic loops with views and native types. That being said, the Numpy implementation of Numba can sometimes also be pretty inefficient (eg. very slow sorting functions compared to Numpy >= 2.0). Thus, put it shortly, I am pretty sure there is a Cython implementation that can be as fast as Numba ;) .

Thanks for all the advice!  Ultimately I had to stop fussing with setuptools and just run python 'myfile.py' with cc.compile() added at the end within a visual studios x64 command window.  This is basically the default numba suggests for AOT, but I still don't understand why their suggested solution for setuptools behaves differently.

If you want to call scipy.optimize.least_squares from within numba compiled code, I have written cminpack_numba and minpack_numba which are equivalent to and significantly faster than least_squares if you are or can use method="lm".

Only current answer: don't try it with setuptools if you're trying to build an independent .[whatevs] from numba code.  Use cc.compile() at the end of your code, run it, and do whatever is necessary to make sure it talks to your c compiler correctly.  On windows, Vis Studio works, run 'python yourfile.py' from the appropriate visual studio Native Tools Command Prompt.  Getting cython to work from setuptools with your compiler doesn't automatically make numba work with it.
